# How does $\frac{x_{n}+(\frac{a}{x_{n}})}{2}$ become $ \frac{ x_{n}^{2} + a}{2x_{n}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My algebra is very rusty.

Could someone please explain the steps to transform the second expression into the third in the following equation for the Babylonian Square Root Algorithm?

$$x _{n + 1} = \frac{x_{n} + (\frac{a}{x_{n}})}{2} =\frac{ x_{n}^{2} + a}{2x_{n}}$$

Comment: $$\frac{x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}}{2}\cdot\color{red}{1}=
\frac{x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}}{2}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{x_n}{x_n}}=
\frac{\left(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}\right)\cdot \color{red}{x_n}}{2\cdot \color{red}{x_n}}=\frac{x_n^2+a}{2x_n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple.

$$\frac{x_n + \bigg(\frac{a}{x_n}\bigg)}{2}=\frac{\frac{{x_n}^2 + a}{x_n}}{2}=\frac{{x_n}^2 + a}{2x_n}$$

Compare with the numerical example

$$\frac{5 + \bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)}{2}=\frac{\frac{{5}^2 + 3}{5}}{2}=\frac{{5}^2 + 3}{2\cdot{5}}$$

where I have set $x_n = 5$ and $a = 3$.